# Выбор значения из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив `$ArrayPapirus`:

```
$ArrayPapirus[$GoodsFormat['id']]['Cost'] = $PapirusCost;
$ArrayPapirus[$GoodsFormat['id']]['OnXY'] = $OnXY;
```

надо выбрать единственное значение 
с максимальным показателем по `OnXY` и минимальным показателем по `Cost`

Comment: дак как вы решали то? 1) найдите максимум, 2) найдите минимум. 3) Найдите элемент, который содержит эти значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, ваш исходный массив:

```
$arrayPapirus = [
    ['onXY' => 10, 'Cost' => 30],
    ['onXY' => 10, 'Cost' => 30],
    ['onXY' => 20, 'Cost' => 20],
    ['onXY' => 20, 'Cost' => 20],
    ['onXY' => 30, 'Cost' => 10, 'winner' => true],
    ['onXY' => 30, 'Cost' => 15],
];
```

Находим искомые максимальное `onXY` и минимальное `Cost`:

```
$maxXY   = max(array_column($arrayPapirus, 'onXY'));
$minCost = min(array_column($arrayPapirus, 'Cost'));
```

Фильтруем массив, и оставляем только те элементы, где достигается максимум и минимум:

```
$result = array_filter($arrayPapirus, function($el) use ($maxXY, $minCost){
                  return ($el['onXY'] == $maxXY) && ($el['Cost'] == $minCost); 
              });
```

Имеем результат:

```
Array (
    [4] => Array
        (
            [onXY] => 30
            [Cost] => 10
            [winner] => 1
        )
)
```

Если предположить, что результат действительно единственный, то берем одно значение из массива (`array_shift`, `array_pop`, `array_values(...)[0]`)